# Copying the content of a character array to a QString in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, character-arrays

I have a character pointer that in any run can have different length. For example:

```
char*  myChar;
```

In one run its content can be *"Hi"* and in another run it can be *"Bye"*.

I want to copy the content of `myChar` to a QString, for example if I have:

```
QString myString;
```

I want to copy the content of `myChar` to `myString`; how can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you use the Constructor ( QString myString(myChar) ) ?

Comment: Yes if mychar is null-terminated, juste use myString = myChar

Comment: I don't want the pointer to myString to be equal to the pointer to myChar. In part of the code I want copy the content of myChar to myString, but later when myChar changes I don't want that myString to be changed.

Comment: What? I was sure QString would make it's own copy of myChar. Is this an assumption or have you tested it?

Comment: @gogoprog and ahenderson: you guys are right it make it's own copy. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It seems that although QString keeps its own copy of string, trying to access its byte array via toLocal8Bit().data() gives a pointer to the original string it's copied from, rather than the one it's holding.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `QString::fromLatin1(const char*)`, `QString::fromLocal8Bit(const char*)` or `QString::fromUtf8(const char*)` as appropriate.  Note that you can't just copy the data  because QStrings contain 16-bit Unicode characters.  It will always need to decode the 8-bit representation.

Comment: @TJ1 It is written already. Take a look here: http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qstring.html#fromUtf8 If you mean code: QString myString = QString::fromUtf8(myChar);

Comment: @besworland `myString` is a class variable that I have defined in my class definition somewhere else. so if I use the command that you showed doesn't it mean it is defined again and will be a local variable not my class variable?

Comment: Hmm.. Then just code: this->myString = QString::fromUtf8(myChar);   :)

Comment: @TJ1 Yes, in this case it will be defined once again. In your class you can simply assign any value to myString.